# How do you open a self closing window with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, window

I've searched the Internet for about four days and read most SO posts about window.open().

I have an array of about 1K URLs. The URLs load a page from an external, third party site. The URLs contain encoded attributes that are read by the external script and processed. After the page has loaded, everything is finished so the only action is to close the window.

I use a button with an event handler to open ten windows. Sorry, it has to be windows. The external script prohibits iframes, images, etc. I have everything working except I can't figure out how to add an event listener to the child window to tell it to close itself after the page has loaded. Right now I have to manually close the windows.

Is there a way to open a window with JS and have the window self close once the page is loaded?

HTML button:

```
<button type="button" id="ph_button" onclick=function(){dispense()}>Open 10</button>
```

JS:

```
var plnx=[
  "http://external.domain.com/pages/page.php?post_id=1460662058&hd=YTo0OntzOj...",
  ...
]

var n=0;

function childWind(i){
    var e=window.open(plnx[i],"_blank",'');
    //Fail attempt to add self.close() to child windows
    /*e[e.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent']( (e.attachEvent ? 'on' : '') + 'load', function() { e.close(); }, false );
    return false;*/
}

function dispense(){
    if(n <plnx.length-9){
        for(var i=n;i<n+10;i++){childWind(i)}
        n+=10;
    }else{
        for(var i=n;i<plnx.length;i++){childWind(i)}
    }
    return n;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: if it's off-site then you can't use any events, but you could use a timer to call `e.close()`

Comment: @dandavis Thanks. I appreciate the help.